# Disable Exception Handling

Tags: vb.net, exception

Is there a way to disable Exception Handling to debug a problem?

I have a fragment of code that takes about ten minutes to error.  It is complex.

If I could disable exception handling then the stack trace is printed to the webpage showing what line caused the error.  As there is exception handling it can sometimes take hours to find what line of code caaused the error.

I want the code to stop (breakpoint) when ever an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which version of Visual Studio you have, but in VS 2008 you can configure exceptions handling in the menu Debug -> Exceptions... and you can check/uncheck exceptions that you wan't to break on.

Comment: I cannot find System.InvalidCastException in that list.

Comment: It is located in Common Language Runtime Exceptions -> System -> System.InvalidCastException

Answer (score 0):

I use this extension
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/50091e25-9e75-40d3-9780-a05892f474de

It adds a toolbar button to visual studio that can quickly toggle breaking for all extensions on or off.

Install the extension and when you want VS to stop when ANY exception is thrown go in to debug and toggle it on.  VS will now break whenever an exception is thrown, even if it is inside a try/catch block.  Don't forget to turn it off again when you are done or it will drive you mad.